# Include periods in end title names in references

Tags: bibliographies, lyx, natbib, custom-bib

I have a LaTeX document using the custom bibliography to build bibliographies. I would like to know how I may include periods at end of titles. I created my custom bst using LaTeX `makebst` program.

Here is my working [MWE](https://github.com/mafenialpha/Custom-Bibliography-/blob/master/document.tex). I want my references to print as follows:

> Mada J, Idzumi M and Tokihiro T 2005 Path description of conserved
> quantities of generalized periodic box-ball systems. *Journal of
> mathematical physics* **46(2)**:022701

Notice there is addition of period between article title and Journal name.

Comment: I seem to remember that this has to do with the block-separator, but changing that in the already created .bst file could be complicated. You may be lucky, but in general it is hard to find anybody who still understands the .bst-language. If you have the possibility, I would strongly recommend to switch to BibLaTeX, which offers much more functionality.

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf the references presented here is it possible to compile them with BibLaTeX without the .bst Language?

Comment: Certainly, and very easily so. Just have a look [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13509/biblatex-in-a-nutshell-for-beginners) and [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex) for some quick guides how to switch to BibLaTeX.

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf I tryed your way but thats not easy way. The easy way is to use custom bib. Your way will involve a lot of fixes.

Comment: It certainly requires some learning, but is the much more flexible method. So if you want to stick to LaTeX in the future, it is well worth investing the time. And frankly speaking, there are hardly any "fixes" needed, because basically (i.e. with standard output) BibLaTeX is fully compatible with BibTeX documents. It only requires replacing `\bibliography{Lit}` with `\printbibliography`, adding `addbibresource{Lit.bib}` in the preamble, and deleting `\bibliographystyle{}`. Hardly any work at all.

Comment: However, if you insist to stay with BibTeX you cannot ecpect to get any help with the question you posted. In this case you have to provide a minimal working example: a preamble with only the most necessary packages and `\documentclass` and a short text between `\begin{document}`--`\end{document}` demonstrating the problem (in your case, producing a citation). Since you use a custom bst-file, you will have to provide this one as well in this case, because noone else has access to it and knows what's in there.

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf I have already included MWE. I put it at Github because it has more lines because of the bst file.

Comment: I see, my bad. But unfortunately I do not know much about the .bst language. I think you either have to change `FUNCTION {new.block}` in a way that inserts a period, or define a new function that does that, and then insert a call to this function in `FUNCTION {article}` probably after `format.title "title"`. But I am not sure if that works and how exactly. Maybe ask someone who actually knows this language.

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf I am really looking for such solution. The problem as you may have noted is to identify where I need to change. I formulated this with makebst program and I have little knowledge of the Language used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the references to be print as you wish you need to change one function in your used bibliography style file `research.bst`.  Search for function `format.title` and change it to (I added `add.period$ " " *` to add the period and a blank):

```
FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title
    duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    { "t" change.case$ 
      add.period$ " " * 
    }
    if$
    "title" bibinfo.check
}
```

With the following MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{mada2005path,
  Title     = {Path description of conserved quantities of generalized periodic box-ball systems},
  Author    = {Mada, Jun and Idzumi, Makoto and Tokihiro, Tetsuji},
  Year      = {2005},
  Number    = {2},
  Pages     = {022701},
  Volume    = {46},
  Journal   = {Journal of mathematical physics},
  Publisher = {AIP Publishing},
}
@Article{maday1988error,
  Title   = {Error analysis for spectral approximation of the Korteweg-de Vries equation},
  Author  = {Maday, Y and Quarteroni, A},
  Year    = {1988},
  Number  = {3},
  Pages   = {499--529},
  Volume  = {22},
  Journal = {RAIRO-Mod{\'e}lisation math{\'e}matique et analyse num{\'e}rique},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}


\begin{document}
I try to cite here \cite{mada2005path}. 
Cross checking citing here \cite{maday1988error}. 

\bibliographystyle{research} % Changed research.bst !!!!!!
\bibliography{\jobname} 
\end{document}
```

you get the wished result:

[image: resulting pdf]